# Simplify the following expression to A'D' + A'B

Tags: boolean-algebra

= '''' + ''' + '' + ' + '' + ''' + 'D'

I've done the K-Map for the following and got A'D' + A'B but can't figure out how to show the simplification that the K-Map derived.

Comment: `A'D' + A'B` is the simplification. What do you mean you can't figure out how to show it?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: i'm supposed to simplify it to its simplest form using boolean algebra and then name the laws i use beside each step and yes it is homework. i basically just have to show how you get to the simplification without using k map.

Comment: Ok, this is where I point out that you're basically asking us to do the work for you :) more constructively, start by trying to group by B and D', and see how that goes.

Comment: Thank you! Figured it out. Sorry, for that I've just been stuck on this one problem forever and it was frustrating me.